# Excel add in (Content app) How to get rid of top right arrow

Tags: office-addins, office-js, office365-apps, apps-for-office, javascript-api-for-office

Excel add in (Content app) How to get rid of top right arrow.
[image]
This element(div) is auto created by app development template.

Answer (score 1):

This is "by design", so there is nothing you can do on your end to get rid of it (I think it actually sits above the web content, and is inaccessible to the DOM altogether).  But there had been some discussion of possibly finding an alternate pattern, at least in task panes.  Let me talk to my team about this.

Comment: Yes it sits above the web content and **my content hides behind it**

Answer (score 0):

The top right icon is a Personality Menu button per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/content-add-ins). As Michael said, it is placed there "by design" and can not be removed.
The browser version of the Excel doesn't have it but Mac and Windows do.

You can conditionally move the content that is hidden by the button using the [Office.PlatformType enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.platformtype?view=excel-js-preview).